# C++ BinarySearchTree Inserting an element

Tags: c++

So I'm getting these errors when trying to insert to a binary search tree, I've literally been stuck on this one problem for hours not knowing what to do and I couldn't find anything on the internet to help so thanks in advance.

```
In file included from Indexer.h:19,
                 from Indexer.cpp:20:
BinarySearchTree.h: In member function ‘void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::insert(const Comparable&, BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::BinaryNode*&) [with Comparable = Word]’:
BinarySearchTree.h:108:   instantiated from ‘void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::insert(const Comparable&) [with Comparable = Word]’
Indexer.cpp:109:   instantiated from here
BinarySearchTree.h:165: error: passing ‘const Word’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool Word::operator<(Word&)’ discards qualifiers
BinarySearchTree.h:167: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘t->BinarySearchTree<Word>::BinaryNode::element < x’
Word.h:33: note: candidates are: bool Word::operator<(Word&)
make: *** [Indexer.o] Error 1
```

And the Code I think is creating it is from Indexer.cpp line 109

Word takes in two parameters, current being the string and count is equal to 0 for this function.

```
Indexer.cpp

            BinarySearchTree<Word> filterTree;
  Line 109: filterTree.insert(Word(current, count));


BinarySearchTree.h

  void insert( const Comparable & x )
  {
    Line:108  insert( x, root );
  }

Word.cpp :operator<

bool Word::operator<(Word &RHS)
{
  if(m_wordText < RHS.GetWord())
    {
      return true;
    }
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If a function returns a member variable directly (and not a local variable) and the type is large, you can change the return type to const reference for a small performance improvement. Eg `const string& Word::GetWord() const`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member comparators should (almost) always be `const` functions that take `const` parameters,

```
bool Word::operator<(Word const&) const;
```

Any function called within a `const` function must also be `const` itself

```
std::string Word::GetWord() const;
```

(As @NeilKirk correctly points out this should probably return `std::string const&`).

You should learn about `const` correctness as it can stop you from making silly mistakes in your code.

Also using a non-member comparator is usually preferred as it allows both sides of the expression to use conversion operators

```
bool operator<(Word const& lhs, Word const& rhs)
{
  return lhs.GetWord() < rhs.GetWord();
}
```